# Unable to get rid of top margin in Bootstrap5 container

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a simple div container block as below block that leaves a large gap at the top.

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>
```

I have tried adding different margin options such as `mt-0`, even `mt-n5` (for negative margin), etc. but nothing seems to get rid of the top margin

```
<div class="container mt-0">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this is a **question** and answer site. You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Bootstrap containers don't have any top or bottom margins by default. Go and inspect your elements using the dev tools to see what *is* causing the unwanted large gap.

Comment: @Cooleronie : You are correct. I tested this as a blank page with two div container blocks and there is no gap. My page, with the rest of everything in it, also has two container blocks one below the other. And there is a large gap between them.  If I merge the container blocks the gaps go away. There is no other statement between them. I suppose there is something else on the page that is causing this, but unsure how to figure that out.

Comment: @Senthil To figure it out: Right click anywhere on your page in the browser and click on the option "Inspect" (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) which will directly open the Developer tools. Now you can inspect your elements live. There are multiple ways to find where the gap comes from. One for example is by hovering over the elements in the DevTools which will highlight the element on the page and show their margins (orange) and padding (green). For more information, use Google and search for "How to inspect Elements".

Comment: I did the inspect and the 2nd DIV block highlights with the margin above followed by whatever I have inside the div. I know it's frustrating.